# The Number Stream detection

Tags: python

How to create a function `NumberStream(str)` that takes the str parameter being passed which will contain the numbers 2 through 9, and determine if there is a consecutive stream of digits of at least N length where N is the actual digit value.

If so, program should return the string true, otherwise, program should return the string false. For example: if str is "6539923335" then the program should return the string true because there is a consecutive stream of 3's of length 3.

I have written the code but it needs some changes to perform as desired:

```
def NumberStream(str):
    global j
    l = len(str)
    count = 0
    res = str[0]
    print("Length of the string is ", l)
    for i in range(l):
        count += 1
        cur_count = 1
        print("Looping")
        for j in range(i+1, l):
            if str[i] != str[j]:
                break
            cur_count += 1
            print(str[i], " and ", str[j], " with cur_count = ", cur_count, " and count = ", count)
        if str[i] == str[j-1] and str[j-1] == cur_count:
            return


print(NumberStream("6539923335"))
```

Comment: `return the string true, otherwise, program should return the string false` - Probably not strings but `False` and `True` values? In your code, you don't return anything at all, not even "string true"/"string false" (== you implicitly return `None`).

Comment: Thanks @h4z3...the above code is unfortunately completing all the for loops and not breaking out even when 3 repeats consecutively three time (for an example)...what change I need to make here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. But first of all I strongly advise you not to use inbuilt functions as variable names. By using the name `str` you overwrite the function `str()` and therefore the shown code can't work. All you have to do is in your comparison before the `return` put a `str(cur_count)` instead of the direct variable. You are otherwise comparing an integer with a string and it will always return False. For that however you have to change the variable name `str` to something else like `string` the code would look like this:

```
def NumberStream(string):
    global j
    l = len(string)
    count = 0
    res = string[0]
    print("Length of the string is ", l)
    for i in range(l):
        count += 1
        cur_count = 1
        print("Looping")
        for j in range(i+1, l):
            if string[i] != string[j]:
                break
            cur_count += 1
            print(string[i], " and ", string[j], " with cur_count = ", cur_count, " and count = ", count)
        if string[i] == string[j-1] and string[j-1] == str(cur_count):
            return "True"
    return "False"


print(NumberStream("6539923335"))
```

Here some other solutions for it:

A very simple solution for this would be to just generate the number of consecutive numbers as a string and test, if they are in the string.

```
test_str = "6539923335"

def NumberStream(input_str):
    for i in range(10):
        consec_num = str(i)*i
        if consec_num in input_str:
            print("Found", consec_num)
            return "True"
    return "False"

print(NumberStream(test_str))
```

Or if you want to do it using a for loop:

```
test_str = "6539923335"

def NumberStream(input_str):
    consec_count = 1
    for j, number in enumerate(input_str):
        if j == 0:
            continue
        if number == input_str[j-1]:
            consec_count += 1
        else:
            consec_count = 1
        if str(consec_count) == number:
            print ("Found consecutive numbers:", number)
            return "True"
    return

NumberStream(test_str)
```

Comment: Thanks @LeoE...we would want the code to detect whether the digit is repeating consecutively the same number of times as the digit itself...so, passing "6539923335" should return True as '3' is repeating 3 times consecutively but passing "5556293383563665" should return False as none of the digit repeats as many times as the digit (ie '5' should repeat 5 times consecutively, but in this string it repeats just 3 times at the beginning).

Comment: Updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: For the first simple solution using generating `consec_num = str(i)*i`, it should be noted that it will always return `"True"` since the loop also includes the case of `i == 0`. So this part of the loop should be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

If permitted, a regular expression can replace all the counting and accounting logic:

```py
import re

def number_stream(s):
    pattern = '|'.join([f'{n}{{{n}}}' for n in range(2, 10)])
    return str(bool(re.search(pattern, s)))
```

`pattern` is an alternation of each digit and the required number of repetitions: `'2{2}|3{3}|4{4}...'`.

Comment: Or if we try to be short: `return str(any(n*int(n)in s for n in s))`.

Comment: @KellyBundy yes - probably more applicable to the second example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036281/5320906).  I was just interested in exploring what regex solutions might work: expanding all the repetitions feels a bit hacky, but it turned out to be the neatest I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
t = "5723399999999"
def function(j):
    k = len(j)
    count = 1
    a = []
    for i in j:
        i = int(i)
        a.append(i)
    for index,i in enumerate(a): 
        try:
            if a[index]== a[index+1]:
                count = count+1
                if count == a[index+1]:
                    count = 1
                    return True
            if a[index]!=a[index+1]:
                count = 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return False

  function(t)
```

here is the code for  Number Stream detection or  continuous number in list

Answer (score -1):

```
function NstreamsOfNumberN (str) {
    
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        
        let numBeingConsidered = Number(str[i]);
                
        let numOfComparisonsToBeDone = numBeingConsidered - 1;
        
        for (let j = i; j < numOfComparisonsToBeDone + i; j++) {
                
            if (str[j] != str[j+1]) {break}//compare neigbourin nums

            else if ((j - i + 1) === numOfComparisonsToBeDone)  
            { let theNwithNstreams = numBeingConsidered
              return [str, (theNwithNstreams), true]} 

        //(j - i + 1) equals num of comparisons that has been done.
        }
    }
    return false 
}

NstreamsOfNumberN('334775555583444582')

9 streams of the number 9 
8 streams of the number 8 
7 streams of the number 7 ...
3 streams of the number 3
2 streams of the number 2.
```

Comment: This question is about Python.

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import operator
def NumberStream(string):
    count={}
    for i in range(len(string)-1):
        if string[i]==string[i+1]:
            count[str(i)]=string[i]
            count[str(i+1)]=string[i+1]
    print(count)   
    res=defaultdict(int)
    for key, item in count.items():
        res[item]+=1
    print(res)
    stream=0
    for key, item in res.items():
        if int(key)== item:
            stream=key
    
    if int(stream)> 0:
        return "true"
    else: return "false"
```

This is my solution

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
def NumberStream(string):

    j=0

    for i in string:

        j=i*int(i)

        if j in string:

            return True

            break

    else:
        return False


print(NumberStream("653999923335"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String numberStream(String s) {
    char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        int cur_count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ch.length; j++) {
            if (ch[i] != ch[j]) {
                break;
            }
            cur_count += 1;
            if (Integer.toString(cur_count).equals(ch[i] + "")) {
                return "true";
            }
        }
    }
    return "false";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).